# How to do a method that itself evokes in the class

Tags: javascript, class, dom, methods

how to do a method that itself evokes in the class, because i wants to create element DOM inside method.

```
  constructor({ message,position }) {
    this.position = position;
    this.message = message;
  }

  createElement(){
    /.creaate element DOM../
  }

}

let mymenu = new Menu({
  message:'text',
  position:'left'
})
```

Comment: You mean recursion? Or it gets called upon creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call the method in the class constructor. Try this:

```js
class Menu {
    constructor({ message, position }) {
        this.position = position;
        this.message = message;
        this.createElement();
    }

    createElement() {
        console.log('creating DOM element..');
    }
}

let mymenu = new Menu({
    message: 'text',
    position: 'left',
});
```